# Register Shopware hook using the 5.2 plugin system

Tags: shopware

I'm developing a Shopware plugin using the 5.2 plugin system and I'm having trouble registering a hook into a method of the sBasket module.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get notified when an article is removed from the shopping basket, to be able to remove other articles automatically (the articles are correlated and it doesn't make sense to have one in the basket if the other one is removed).

So far my plugin bootstrap looks as follows:

```
class MyTestPlugin extends \Shopware\Components\Plugin {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {

        return [
                'Shopware_Modules_Basket_AddArticle_Start' => 'onBasketAddArticle',
                'sBasket::sDeleteArticle::after' => 'onBasketDeleteArticle'
        ];
    }

    // Handler methods declared here...
}
```

The "AddArticle_Start" event registration works as expected, that is, the "onBasketAddArticle" handler is called when I add articles to the basket. The sBasket hook, however, isn't invoked.

I suspect that I'm mixing up legacy and new plugin system here and that hooks maybe have to be registered another way than events, but I can't find anything in the Shopware documentation.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

At last, I found the solution. For anyone running into the same problem:

Shopware has a lot of caches and one of them is the proxy cache. Shopware creates proxy classes containing information about the registered hooks and those classes don't get rebuilt when updating a plugin.

So, if you add/remove/change hook registrations, you have to clear the proxy cache. In the backend go to Settings / Caches/Performace / Caches/Performance, select the checkbox "Proxies and meta data" and click the clear button.

Answer (score 2):

You can clean any cache in install/enable actions next way:

```
public function install(Shopware\Components\Plugin\Context\InstallContext\InstallContext $context){
    parent::install($context);
    // Only proxy cahe
    $context->scheduleClearCache( array( Shopware\Components\Plugin\Context\InstallContext\InstallContext::CACHE_TAG_PROXY ) );
}

public function activate(Shopware\Components\Plugin\Context\InstallContext\ActivateContext $context)
{
    // Clear all caches
    $context->scheduleClearCache( array( Shopware\Components\Plugin\Context\InstallContext\InstallContext::CACHE_LIST_ALL ) );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just found that out today. In fact, at least in the 5.2 plugin system, this is done in the default implementation of activate, update and delete. The problem that I had was that I installed/updated my plugin using the console tool and that doesn't seem to execute the scheduled cache clearance (but it supports a separate command to clear the cache). Installing the plugin via the backend plugin manager, however, works as expected - cache is cleared. Anyway, thanks for the answer.